# Why is this.props.componentId needed?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Why is `this.props.componentId` needed?

What is its purpose?

Why can't we use the library without that id being needed?

`react-navigation` doesn't need something like that, and `react-native-navigation` v1 didn't use anything like that. So why does v2 needs and uses that? The reason I ask is firstly to understand it, and secondly to see if I can skip this since now I cannot use RNN v2 from a saga.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a detailed answer from a [blogpost](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/react-native-navigation-v2-is-here-5b7c87f002a) by the `react-native-navigation` library [developer](https://medium.com/@drorbiran).

> So now we want to enable the following behavior: after user clicks on the text, the app pushes the `ViewPost` screen. Later on it will be very easy to attach the same function to a list item instead of the text. To push a new screen into this screen’s navigation stack, we will use `Navigation.push`. **In the new API this method expects to receive the current componentId which can be found in props.componentID**. So in `PostsList.js` we create a `pushViewPostScreen` function and attach it to the onPress event of the Text.

```html
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native-ui-lib';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';

class PostsList extends PureComponent {

  static propTypes = {
    navigator: PropTypes.object,
    componentId: PropTypes.string
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.pushViewPostScreen = this.pushViewPostScreen.bind(this);
  }

  pushViewPostScreen() {
    // We pass the componentId to Navigation.push
    // to reference the which component will be pushed
    // to the navigation stack

    Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
      component: {
        name: 'blog.ViewPost',
        passProps: {
          text: 'Some props that we are passing'
        },
        options: {
          topBar: {
            title: {
              text: 'Post1'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <View flex center bg-blue60>
        <Text onPress={this.pushViewPostScreen}>Posts List Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default PostsList;
```

In the [official docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/screen-api), it seems that the Screen API, which is responsible of pushing, popping and changing navigation, will be accessible through the `Navigation` module always expecting a `props.componentId` to get the reference to the component.

Comment: Thanks, but my question remains. Why is it needed in the new API? What is its purpose? All I can get from the above is that it is needed, but not the reason.